# `contenteditable` with `white-space: pre-wrap` - newline insertion

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I'd like to create a `contenteditable` element with CSS set to `white-space: pre-wrap`, where the default behavior on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> is simply to insert a newline (the element's `textContent` should then exactly match its appearance).

Having gone through several attempts at getting this to work properly, this is still causing me huge headaches. By default, inserting a newline at the *end* of such an element:

- Fails to make the newline visible, even with `white-space: pre-wrap`
- Fails to allow the user to place the caret at the newline position
- Fails to include the newline in the element's `textContent`

My best attempt so far is the following:

```js
const trg = document.querySelector('#trg')

const insertNewline = e => {
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '\n!')
    document.execCommand('delete')
}

trg.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        e.preventDefault()

        insertNewline(e)
    }
})

trg.addEventListener('input', e => {
    const { currentTarget } = e
    const { textContent, innerText } = currentTarget

    console.log({ textContent, innerText })
})

trg.focus()
```

```css
#trg {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="trg" contenteditable></div>
```

I've logged both `textContent` and `innerText` for comparison — `innerText` is of little use in this case, because a single keypress adds two `\n`s to it for some reason.

Without the `insertNewline` logic or without the immediately deleted `!`, it requires two keypresses to insert a single newline at the end of the input.

It's unclear *why* this is the case, and more importantly, the immediately deleted character messes up the element's undo history — press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> end you end up with an unwanted `!`. The `!` can be replaced with basically any character, including something like a zero-width space, but I've left it as something visible to best illustrate the undo history problem.

Any thoughts on how to improve this?

Comment: You may want to look at [MDN's documentation for the `contenteditable` feature's differences among browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content#Differences_in_markup_generation).