# ContentEditable div produces 2 new lines for every return

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I am trying to display a `div` that is using `white-space: pre` style and allows for editing.

However, every time a new line is inserted from the keyboard, and then the contents is read back from the div using `innerText` 2 new lines are obtained instead of 1. I understand the browser is implicitly wrapping lines in `<div>`'s and inserting `<br>`'s. However, I am not sure how to obtain a textual representation of the `div` that is accurate.

E.g. to demonstrate. in the following, after entering `1<return>2<return><return>3` in the editable div, the following is obtained (where the second is a direct `innerText` copy between two `div`s and the third is the actual `innerHTML` shown):
[image]

I have put together a simple fiddle showing this: https://jsfiddle.net/mv2h4Lnp/1/

### Possible Solution

It sounds very much like the issue experienced when [FireFox changed from using `br` to `div`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52817606/) in generated markup. However, the solution presented in that article is FireFox specific and essentially makes FireFox behave like before it was changed to wrap lines in `div`s.

I also noticed the following SO questions [`contenteditable` with `white-space: pre-wrap` - newline insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50441833/5660642) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54926262/5660642 that give a suggestion that its best to handle the  `onkeydown` event and deal with the new lines instead of leaving to the browser.

Reusing that as a basis, I updated the fiddle to use ideas from the above articles as: https://jsfiddle.net/mv2h4Lnp/2/

Essentially, the following code has been used to intercept the return key:

```js
document.getElementById('ss').addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br>');
  }
});
```

While this mostly works. I notice that when there is already a `<br>` where the caret is when the return key is pressed it does not insert another `<br>` and simply moves the caret forward one character. This is not what I am looking for, and I dont really understand why another `<br>` is not inserted as the `insertHTML` is called.

Instead, if the above JavaScript is updated to insert a `\n` instead of a `<br>` it works in the fiddle perfectly, but when running outside of the fiddle in Chrome it still generates spurious newlines as it still tries to wrap lines in `<div>`'s - so the `<br>` is probably the way to go.

Is there any better way of getting the text back from a `div` that has the same number of new lines as it displays? I really dont care how its structured in the `div`, just that I can access the plain text again. I feel like I am missing something obvious.

#### Update: FireFox

Just testing in FF80, it works fine with `document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br>');` so maybe its Chrome (tested at version 85) this does not work properly with.